# Extracting values from a dictionary by key, string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror, traceback

I'm trying to extract values from dictionary recieved with websocket-client via key and for some reason it throws me an error "String indices must be integers".
no matter how im trying to do it im constantly getting the same error unless i'm writing it as lines of code then it works, unfotunately that's not what I'm after...

**Example:**

```
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("websocket link")

info = ws.recv()
print(info["c"])

ws.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\project\venv\example\example.py", line 14, in <mod
ule>
    print(info["c"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

While if im taking the same dictionary and writing it down suddenly it works...

**Example:**

```
example = {"a":"hello","b":123,"c":"whatever"}
print(example["c"])
```

**Output:**

```
whatever
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**SOLUTION**

firstly you have to import the websocket and json module as you receive dictionary json object and then you have to load that json objects.

```
import websocket
import json

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("websocket link")

info = json.loads(ws.recv())
print(info["c"])

ws.close()
```

Comment: `websocket.WebSocket.recv()` seems to return a string, you need to parse it and turn it into a Python data structure if you want to access it that way. I assume you're getting JSON from the other side so try first running it through JSON parser (e.g. `info = json.loads(ws.recv())`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the dictionary you receive from the web socket is a json object:

```
import websocket
import json

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("websocket link")

info = json.loads(ws.recv())
print(info["c"])

ws.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to import the websocket and json module as you receive dictionary json object
and then you have to load that json objects.

```
import websocket
import json
```

and then load

```
info = json.loads(ws.recv())
```